# Convert to True/False values of Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a rather big dataframe that looks a bit like this:

```
  | obj1  | obj2  | obj3  |
  |------------------------
0 | attr1 | attr2 | attr1 |
1 | attr2 | attr3 | NaN   |
2 | attr3 | attrN | NaN   |
```

I'm new(ish) to pandas but I can't figure out a way to make it look like this:

```
      | obj1  | obj2  | obj3 |
      ------------------------
attr1 | True | False | True  |
attr2 | True | False | False |
attr3 | True | False | False |
```

what's the most pythonic/fast way to go around this?

**EDIT**

I don't have any column in the dataframe with all the attributes.
I could have an Obj4 that has an attribute which is not seen anywhere else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html):

```
df = df.set_index('obj1', drop=False).rename_axis(None)
df = df.eq(df['obj1'], axis=0)
print (df)
       obj1   obj2   obj3
attr1  True  False   True
attr2  True  False  False
attr3  True  False  False
```

Similar solution:

```
df = df.set_index('obj1', drop=False).rename_axis(None)
df = df.eq(df.index.values, axis=0)
print (df)
       obj1   obj2   obj3
attr1  True  False   True
attr2  True  False  False
attr3  True  False  False
```

And numpy solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values == df['obj1'].values[:, None], 
                  index=df['obj1'].values, 
                  columns=df.columns)
print (df)
       obj1   obj2   obj3
attr1  True  False   True
attr2  True  False  False
attr3  True  False  False
```

EDIT:

For compare all values it is not easy:

```
vals = df.stack().unique()
L = [pd.Series(df[x].unique(), index=df[x].unique()).reindex(index=vals) for x in df.columns]
df1 = pd.concat(L, axis=1, keys=df.columns)
print (df1)
        obj1   obj2   obj3
attr1  attr1    NaN  attr1
attr2  attr2  attr2    NaN
attr3  attr3  attr3    NaN
attrN    NaN  attrN    NaN

df1 = df1.eq(df1.index.values, axis=0)
print (df1)
        obj1   obj2   obj3
attr1   True  False   True
attr2   True   True  False
attr3   True   True  False
attrN  False   True  False
```

EDIT1:

Another solution for `df1`:

```
stacked = df.stack()
#reshape to MultiIndex
df1 = stacked.reset_index(name='A').set_index(['level_1','A'])
#MultiIndex with all possible values
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.index.levels[0], stacked.unique()])
#reindex by MultiIndex
df1 = df1.reindex(index=mux)
#replace non NaN values to second level of MultiIndex
df1['level_0'] = df1['level_0'].mask(df1['level_0'].notnull(),
                                     df1.index.get_level_values(1))
#reshape back
df1 = df1['level_0'].unstack(0)
print (df1)
        obj1   obj2   obj3
attr1  attr1    NaN  attr1
attr2  attr2  attr2    NaN
attr3  attr3  attr3    NaN
attrN    NaN  attrN    NaN
```

Comment: That looks about right, but what if I have no object with all attributes?
additional info: I created this dataframe from a defaultdict(list)

Comment: Can you add sample for it? Do you think you dont need compare with first column?

Comment: I don't have a column to compare, the idea is to take all different values from the whole set of data and compare with each Series. Creating an Index Column with the attributes and the true or false value for each object

Comment: Ok, so if unique values are `['attr1' 'attr2' 'attr3' 'attrN' 'attr4']` what is desired output by your input dataframe?

Comment: Thank you very much for accepting. Not easy question, really. You can upvote too - click to small triangle above `4` above accepting mark. Thanks.